# Can i use JsSip in Phonegap build?

Tags: android, cordova, sip, jssip

Can i use The JavaScript SIP Library (JsSip) in my phonegap build?
If i cannot is there any plugins?

Here is JsSip webpage http://www.jssip.net/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like someone is starting this plugin together with PhoneRTC:
https://github.com/versatica/jssip-cordova

Comment: looks like some is not. link is dead.